# Interface Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am wrapping my head around Interfaces and dependency injection. So far I get what the implementation of an interface does, but I am missing something and can't get past it after spending a lot of time reading and watching videos on it.
I have a nice example that uses different mail services, like PHPMailer or OtherMailerService, which are third party libraries. Instead of instantiating the mailer service from within my class (SomeClass) I would inject an instance into the constructor and to make this flexible I would use an Interface.

```
<?php
interface MailerInterface {
    public function send($message);
}
```

I can now type-hint the constructor parameter of my class to protect my class.

```
<?php
class SomeClass{
    public $mailer;
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer) { 
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
    public function sendMailMessage() 
    {
        $mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Now this MailerInterface would need to be implemented in the Mailer service, but this is third party. And I would also need to implement that function send() into a third party, this doesn't feel like I am thinking this right. I spent a lot of time trying to get the concept, but its slipping through  my head.

I am not seeing this clearly, so my question is how would I set up my third party library for a dependency injection? What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get 3rd party libs to implement your interface so you'll need to write some wrapper classes, eg

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

class PHPMailerWrapper implements MailerInterface {
    private $mail;

    public function __construct(PHPMailer $mail) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        // mailer could be configured here or prior to being passed in here
    }

    public function send($message) {
        // super simple example, I don't know PHPMailer very well
        $this->mail->body = $message;
        return $this->mail->send();
    }
}
```

You would need to do something similar for any other implementation you wish to support.

You would then create an instance of one of these implementations and pass it to your `SomeClass` constructor, eg

```php
$mailer = new PHPMailerWrapper($phpMailerInstance);
$someObj = new SomeClass($mailer);
```

Comment: This makes sense. Things fall into place. So this is actually that 'container' that is often mentioned with dependency injection? ..

Comment: No, an IoC container is something to help you create / retrieve instances of types. Have a read of this ~ https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html